# C# Отслеживание изменений данных в таблице MSSQL

Tags: c#, sql-server

Как организовать уведомление программы о том, что определенные данные в базе поменялись? Желательно, чтобы в случае изменения данных в базе запускалась хранимая процедура, возвращающая данные в программу. Есть ли предусмотренные стандартные классы для этого? Вручную не хочется опрашивать.

Comment: Посмотрите это https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/62xk7953(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: matrix, интересно, но он же всё ровно будет делать SELECT по таймеру и смотреть? Это же чисто ради удобства? Или задействован какой-то новый функционал SQL, просто не слышал раньше о таком.

Comment: @xSx, здесь будет использовать механизм внутренних событий СУБД. Функционал не новый, появился еще в SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать класс [SqlDependency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx).

1) Необходимо убедиться, что для целевой БД включен Service Broker

```
SELECT is_broker_enabled FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'Database_name';
```

2) Если Service Broker не включен, то нужно включить его. При этом не должно быть активных соединений с БД

```
ALTER DATABASE [Database_name] SET ENABLE_BROKER;
```

3) Пример C# приложения с [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/62xk7953(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
void Initialization()
{
    // Create a dependency connection.
    SqlDependency.Start(connectionString, queueName);
}

void SomeMethod()
{
    // Assume connection is an open SqlConnection.

    // Create a new SqlCommand object.
    using (SqlCommand command=new SqlCommand(
        "SELECT ShipperID, CompanyName, Phone FROM dbo.Shippers", 
        connection))
    {

        // Create a dependency and associate it with the SqlCommand.
        SqlDependency dependency=new SqlDependency(command);
        // Maintain the refence in a class member.

        // Subscribe to the SqlDependency event.
        dependency.OnChange+=new
           OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);

        // Execute the command.
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // Process the DataReader.
        }
    }
}

// Handler method
void OnDependencyChange(object sender, 
   SqlNotificationEventArgs e )
{
  // Handle the event (for example, invalidate this cache entry).
}

void Termination()
{
    // Release the dependency.
    SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString, queueName);
}
```

В объекте `SqlCommand` после ключевого слова `select` в запросе перечислены поля таблиц БД, изменения значений которых необходимо отслеживать.
Также важно, чтобы была явно указана схема (по умолчанию `dbo`).

При возникновении события вызывается метод `OnDependencyChange`.